# if/then with pixel finding and looping, all of which is above me at the moment

Tags: java

I want to take a screenshot, and if the pixel is the correct value RGB then take another screenshot and find next pixel or else repeat.

this is the code to get the pixel and it works like a charm!

```
{
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    search: for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            if(image.getRGB(x, y) == color3.getRGB())
            {

                break search;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what i want to know i guess is how would i go about asking it to repeat this segment of code until the pixel equals the true color. the color i am looking for is:

```
Color color3 = new Color(114, 46, 33);
```

Ok context, i am building a program that goes through steps, one opens the given puzzle, i have that down because i can use simple pixel data, then it needs to center the mouse on the center pixel. The problem is i cant just use a second get pixel image because it takes a while for the game to open the relevant jpanel so i need my program to wait until it can find a pixel indicating the game is open before it starts to look for the pixel to center the mouse.

Comment: please provide a context for what your doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably separate the screenshot code into a method and call it until you get the desired result:

```
public boolean checkColor(Color inputColor) {
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    for(int x = 0; x < rectangle.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < rectangle.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (image.getRGB(x, y) == inputColor.getRGB()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method will return true if it can find the given `inputColor` in the screenshot. You might then use it in a loop as follows:

```
Color newColor = ...;

while (!checkColor(newColor)) {
    new Color = new Color(114, 46, 33);
    // Or change color in here for every iteration
}
```

This loop will terminate if it can't match the screenshot to `newColor`.